# Unbounded subsets of ordinals with countable confinality

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be limit ordinals such that $\alpha > \beta$ and $cf (\beta) > cf(\alpha) = \omega$. It is not true that we can always find an unbounded subset of $\alpha$ with order type $\beta$: For an uncountable successor cardinal $\kappa$ we can find a counterexample by setting  $\alpha = \kappa + \omega$ and $\beta = \kappa$.
But is it possible to find other values for  $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that there is  an unbounded subset of $\alpha$ with order type $\beta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: if $S\subset\alpha$ is an unbounded subset with order type $\gamma$, then always $cf(\alpha)=cf(\gamma)$.  The inequality $cf(\alpha)\leq cf(\gamma)$ is trivial, since any unbounded sequence in $S$ is an unbounded sequence in $\alpha$.  For the converse, let $\kappa=cf(\alpha)$ and $f:\kappa\to\alpha$ be strictly increasing and unbounded.  For each $\xi<\kappa$, let $g(\xi)$ be the least element of $S$ which is greater than or equal to $f(\xi)$.  Then $g:\kappa\to S$ is nonstrictly increasing and unbounded.  Letting $A\subset\kappa$ be the set of $\xi$ such that $g(\xi)>g(\theta)$ for all $\theta<\xi$, $g:A\to S$ is strictly increasing and unbounded.  Since $A$ has order-type at most $\kappa$, this proves that $cf(\gamma)=cf(S)\leq \kappa=cf(\alpha)$.